# Action is not called before the render() in my React app: cannot read property of null

Tags: reactjs

I got this error when I launch my React app:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

But I do the same thing for my App component with a fetchUser action and everything works. I think my `fetchClients()` is called after the `renderClient()` function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchClients } from '../../actions';

class ClientList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchClients();
  }

  renderClients() {
    return this.props.clients.map(client => { // The error is here
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{client.name.firstName}</td>
          <td>{client.name.lastName}</td>
          <td>{client.email}</td>
          <td>{client.pointsBalance}</td>
          <td>{new Date(client.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Clients</h1>

        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Prénom</th>
              <th>Nom</th>
              <th>Mail</th>
              <th>Montant cagnotte</th>
              <th>Inscrit le</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>{this.renderClients()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ clients }) {
  return { clients };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchClients })(ClientList);
```

Here is where I call my ClientList component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ClientList from '../components/clients/ClientList';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3">
            <Navbar />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-9">
            <Switch>
              // ... 
              <Route path="/clients" component={ClientList} />
              // ...
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**EDIT:** Here is my actions file.

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { FETCH_MERCHANT, FETCH_CLIENTS } from './types';

export const fetchMerchant = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/current_merchant');

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_MERCHANT, payload: res.data.data });
};

export const fetchClients = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/clients');

  console.log(res.data);

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_CLIENTS, payload: res.data.data });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no `clients` prop when you try to render your component. It is an async job. Try conditional rendering:

```
renderClients() {
    return this.props.clients && this.props.clients.map(client => { // The error is here
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{client.name.firstName}</td>
          <td>{client.name.lastName}</td>
          <td>{client.email}</td>
          <td>{client.pointsBalance}</td>
          <td>{new Date(client.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: I added my actions file. I tried your solution but nothing is returned, this.props.clients is empty: `[]`. It should contain 2 objects. I don't understand because in my `fetchMerchant()` method which I call in my App component, it fetch my merchant, and I do the same for my `fetchClients()` method. It should work without the code you suggested me to add.

Comment: My answer solves your problem which described in the question title. With this method if there is nothing before fetch you show nothing, after fetch completed you show the component. But, if nothing comes as prop, this means either your action, reducer or api end point is the problem. What do you see for the console.log you placed in your fetchClients?